# Whois parser doesn't show some details for co and dev domains

Tags: ruby, parsing, whois-ruby

I am trying to use the ruby whois gem but the whois-parser gem doesn't seem to work for  .dev i.e for these I get `Whois::AttributeNotImplemented` errors and doesn't return some details like the expiry date for .co domains, in this case, it returns nil. I understand that there is probably no parser for .dev domains  but not sure what's wrong with .co domains. I am new to all this and even willing to implement a parser. What are possible solutions, I can look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the whois-parser gem is no longer maintained and this fork https://github.com/jarthod/whois-parser solves this issue.